# Querying for an embedded document with @DocumentReference in Spring MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I'm working on a mongoDb project in spring. I have an http request that queries for an embedded object with this structure [Prompt class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUe82.png) first off by the id, which returns the details of the object in the collection, just under the source tag instead of the mood itself [Http requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk7AD.png)(the name of the other collection). How would I make the details in source appear right underneath the mood? I want to get the second of my requests pictured, where I query for all prompts with a matching mood, based on the name. I've considered just using the name, which does work, but then the mood object in the collection has no id assigned to it.

[query on mood.source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO4uH.png) I tried this query but didnt get anything back, and either way I'd like to get the id and name embedded right beneath the mood: if possible. This @DocumentReference was the only way I found to have the id be sent through to the other object. I saw something with specifying the target using lookup, but I was confused on how that works. Thanks for the help